# C# Incorrect Mimetype returned application/octet-stream

Tags: c#, mime-types

I have pilfered a chuck of code from pinkode.net I believe it was - that will find the mimetype of any file. It works great and its much needed. When I push the code to our SSIS package that will call the method, it always returns the same mimetype, application/octet-stream. This is a very narrow use of this method in that I am only evaluating .xls? files. It runs fine on my workstation VS project, but the same code on the server runs fine but returns the same type.

What/where is this kind of behavior defined on a windows 10 server? File associations getting in the way? I am completely at a loss as to why it is not working and havent really tried. I could find and retain the mimetype for the files I know of, but the goal of this ETL process was to be able to parse up any excel to a raw state. Getting mimetype from file is critical to the stated goal and this has been working fine until it lives on a db server.
...

```
public static string getMimeFromFile(string file)
    {
        IntPtr mimeout;
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file))
            throw new FileNotFoundException(file + " not found");

        int MaxContent = (int)new FileInfo(file).Length;
        if (MaxContent > 4096) MaxContent = 4096;
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file);


        byte[] buf = new byte[MaxContent];
        fs.Read(buf, 0, MaxContent);
        fs.Close();
        int result = FindMimeFromData(IntPtr.Zero, file, buf, MaxContent, null, 0, out mimeout, 0);

        if (result != 0)
            throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(result);
        string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeout);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeout);
        return mime;
    }
```

...

Answer (score 1):

> File associations getting in the way?

It seems quite likely - see step 4 in the algorithm here: [MIME Type Detection in Windows Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775147%28v%3Dvs.85%29)

Comment: Hmm. This seems to just describe the problem I have but within the context of Internet Explorer? The big picture for me is I have a Microsoft Flow trigger grabbing file attachments in an email and dumping to a Filestream talble in SQL Server. The service then picks up that file - txt, xls(x), pdf etc and pushes to a ripper for whatever flavor of a file.

Comment: The problem is - my excel ripper needs to know the file type or mimetype because the libraries I have only handle certain Excel files. None of that happens within the context of the web etc. If I run same code on my workstation - it works, but as a script task in an SSIS package - I get this ambiguous.

Comment: From the documentation FindMimeFromData essentially just looks at the file name extension if the file's content doesn't match one of the types it knows. So you could do the same yourself. Or else add a file association for .xls on the server or even install Excel.

Comment: David, thank you! I spoke to my server admin and neither of us wants to install Excel and burn a license esp with no intention of using it on a dedicated db server. So I went to my one registry and just exported any and all xl* extentions and merged to the db server and it seems to work as it did on my machine.

Comment: FYI - for anyone interested. Microsoft has used .xls for 2 very different files or mimetypes- "application/vnd.ms-excel" and  "text/xml". The kicker is that there is only one .xls Class file association which is to the vnd.ms-excel. So the registry doesn't know about text/xml at all but the method opens .xls file that is actually xml Excel and assigns it the ambiguous type which is good enough for my use. Hope that makes sense. If there were 3rd type using .xls then I would be in trouble. Hope that makes sense